# RadTreeView only allow Lowest Child Node to be Droppable

Tags: c#, telerik

I'm trying to create a functionality where I have two RadTreeViews where the end user can Drag from one TreeView to another. However I only want the user to be able to Drag the Lowest Child Node over to the Destination TreeView.  I also only want the destination TreeView to only allow one level of nodes (no childnodes).  I've tried all the properties and am still unable to accomplish either of these.

Have Tried accomplishing this like:

```
 foreach (var n in treeViewSource.Nodes[0].Nodes)
 {
     n.AllowDrop = false;
 }
```

However it doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to do.  I've also tried doing this through limiting what can be Dragged into the Destination TreeView using the Drop, NodeAdding ect Events and it's not functioning as I would expect.  Anyone know the proper way to accomplish this functionality ?

[image]

Comment: the code you provided would mean that the drag is not allowed for the nodes at depth=1 (with depth 0 being the root), however that doesn't guarantee that it has no child nodes. The lowest child(leaf/terminal) node would be the node that does not have any children of its own. Instead of going through the whole tree, maybe enable the drag by checking if the selected/clicked/moused node has child nodes?